# Get left and right volume of an android MediaPlayer object

Tags: android, get, volume

I'm dealing with a problem that seems have no solution on the web.
In android it's very simple to set stereo volume of a MediaPlayer object with the method myMediaPlayer.setVolume(leftVolume, rightVolume) but instead it seems there is no way to get the two volumes separately! There is a way to get the volume from an AudioManager object but it just return a mono volume, not stereo. So, how can I get the two volumes?
Hope you can help me!
Thank you in advance